# pydev: undefined variable error when importing compiled modules

Tags: module, pydev, bytecode, python-idle

I want to switch my python-IDE from idle to pydev (eclipse). I am using a couple of modules which I have as compiled bytecode (*.pyc) only. In idle that was never a problem and it even offers code completion for those compiled modules. But pydev gives me a lot of "undefined variable" errors - however the code is interpreted correctly.

Is there a way pydev can handle bytecode modules the way idle does? Perhaps without decompiling the files?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the modules as **forced builtins**.

To do that, go into Settings → PyDev → Interpreter - (Python/Jython/IronPython as approriate), select the interpeter you're using, and add it to the list on the *Forced Builtins* tab ([look here for more details](http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#id1)).

(Note that you may or may not have to add multiple entries for subpackages and modules; for example to get Fabric working properly one needs to add both `fabric` and `fabric.api`)

That makes PyDev load those modules into an interpreter to get code-completion and error checking data, rather than just analysing source code.

I've not tried it for `.pyc` files, but it works for other things like importing something that's generated dynamically by a script's `__init__.py` or something (ie fabric) so it might work for you.

(see also [this FAQ](http://pydev.org/faq.html#what_is_that_forced_builtin_libs_in_the_python_i) and [that one](http://pydev.org/faq.html#code_completion_is_not_working_correctly_for_some) on the PyDev site)